# How to correctly implement fix to make dragging a hidden component downwards work?

Tags: codenameone

When a component is hidden, its height is forced to 0 which prevents the scrolling in `Component` to work when you drag it downwards. Basically, it can be dragged down to edge of the screen, but then no scrolling down happens. This issue was also mentioned earlier in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003540/scrolling-down-not-working-when-dragging-an-element-and-simultaneously-adding-re) where Shai offered a path for investigation.

Any suggestions for a way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Here's a code sample to reproduce the issue (copy/paste into a Hello World project in replacement of the default `start()` method):

```
Image dragImage2;
Component dropPlaceholder;

void saveDragImage(Image dragIm) {
    dragImage2 = dragIm;
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    /* To seee the issue: press and hold a button about 1 second to initiate the drag and drop, 
    then drag down to the lower edge of the screen: the list doesn't scroll down as normally. 

    When dragging upwards in a list (which must of course alreaday be scrolled down a bit), 
    it works as expected: When the dragged button reaches to top of the screen, the list scrolls down. */

    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", new BorderLayout());
    dropPlaceholder = new Label(" ... "); //used to create an empty space in the drop position
    dropPlaceholder.setDropTarget(true);

    Container list3 = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        Button draggableButton = new Button("Button number " + i) {
            @Override
            public void longPointerPress(int x, int y) {
                setDraggable(true);
                setFocusable(true);
                dragImage2 = super.getDragImage();
                setHidden(true);
                Form f = getComponentForm();
                f.pointerPressed(x, y);
                pointerDragged(x - 1, y - 1); //move the dragged element a few pixels to initiate the drag
                pointerDragged(x - 2, y - 2);
            }

            @Override
            protected Image getDragImage() {
                return dragImage2;
            }

            @Override
            protected void dragFinished(int x, int y) {
                setHidden(false);
                if (dropPlaceholder != null)
                    dropPlaceholder.remove(); //remove the placeholder after drag
            }
        };
        draggableButton.setDropTarget(true);

        draggableButton.addDragOverListener((e) -> {
            Component dropTarget = e.getDropTarget(); //may be null (in Component.dragFinishedImpl(int x, int y))
            if (dropTarget != null) {
                Container parent = dropTarget.getParent();
                int index = parent.getComponentIndex(dropTarget);
                dropPlaceholder.remove(); //remove placeholder from previous position
                parent.addComponent(index, dropPlaceholder); //add placeholder at position of dropTarget
            }
            getCurrentForm().revalidate(); //refresh the screen to show the new position of placeholder
        });
        list3.add(draggableButton);
    }
    list3.setScrollableY(true);
    Container cont = hi.getContentPane();
    cont.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, list3);
    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: This hack is wrong, you just stick a hardcoded value to workaround a specific problem you have for which I haven't seen a test case. Scrolling will stop working if components are smaller than the size of the screen. I suggest creating a test case instead of focusing on a workaround

Comment: Yes, it was only a hack :-) I added a test case above to reproduce the issue (sorry it took a bit of time since the actual code handles a lot more specifics that I needed to remove).

Comment: I can't follow the code, there's too much of it. You need to simplify this.

Comment: Thanks for following up. You can ignore the code at the bottom of the post below the "Below the attempt to fix the issue" - I just left that to keep the original text However, I don't think I can reduce the code at the top of the post which illustrates the issue. It requires quite a bit of moving parts to make something that shows the drag and drop effect I'm after (where an empty space below the dragged component shows visually where it will be inserted). To reproduce, just copy into a Hello World and longPress on a button and drag it downwards.

Comment: I realized my first example to reproduce the code had references to stuff I hadn't included. This version is improved and hopefully simplified enough to be more understandable. The inline comment explains how to reproduce the issue. Be aware that drag is initiated on a longPress, to enable combining scrolling AND drag&drop in the same list.

Comment: Why are you setting `draggableButton` as a drop target? I don't understand the logic of setting the component you want to drag to hidden??? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If draggableButton is not a dropTarget, the dragged button's dragOverListener won't get called and the dropPlaceholder doesn't get moved to the new position. And I need to hide the dragged component to avoid leaving a 'blank' spot in its original position. As I tried to explain, the overall effect I want is that the dragged element is removed from its original position. And as it is dragged, a 'blank' space follows below it to indicate visually the exact position where it will get inserted when dropped. This is how I see drag and drop implemented on other platforms.

Comment: Instead of setting it to hidden why not move it to the new place dynamically? Wouldn't that give you that exact effect?

Comment: Thanks again. If I remember well, I tried that approach but there was some snag (maybe it was some part of your implementation which depends on the dragged element remaining in its Container). I just wonder if the drag and scroll can not be made independent of the size of the dragged element. I would think that scrolling speed could depend only on how close the finger is the edge of the screen and not the size of the dragged element. Alternatively, maybe there is another way to get the size of the dragged element that could be overridden to handle a case like this one.

Comment: If you drag a large element its bottom would reach the edge sooner triggering scrolling so yes the size would impact scrolling. If you think scrolling/dragging needs another option perhaps a more effective approach would be to look into the sources for the drag support and try to add an optional additional way: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue, it explains why my earlier hack helped. What is weird is the inconsistency between dragging the hidden element up (which works perfectly) and dragging it down (which basically doesn't work). I've spend hours on trying to figure out what's wrong with the scrolling code in Component (based  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003540/scrolling-down-not-working-when-dragging-an-element-and-simultaneously-adding-re), but I have not managed to understand the code. This is the only thing which is preventing my own D&D from working, so it's quite an issue for me.

Comment: If you don't understand something specific about the code you can file an issue on that and I'll try to help.